# Как сверстать текст в центре кнопки и оформить текстовое описание?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Есть кнопка "Оставить заявку", она имеет градиент, и название которое должно быть размещено по центру, при этом кнопка должна на выходе должно получится https://yadi.sk/i/skcVyiiN3SqdHm

```css
.main-left .buttom {
  /* Style for "Rounded Re" */
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #362753;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ea2363 0%, #ff8a65 100%);
  margin: auto auto 116px 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttom">
  Оставить заявку
</div>
```

И еще есть дополнительное описание услуг, но не получается сделать разделение линий https://yadi.sk/i/8xSiQubY3SqfPm

В коде так

```css
.main-left .priceinfo {
  /*display: inline;*/
  margin: 50px auto 46px 130px;
  width: 292px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #090a0b;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="priceinfo">Оплата только за фактически<br> выполненные работы
</div>
```

Comment: Во-первых, кнопку нужно верстать соответствующими тегами - button или а, в зависимости что должно произойти по нажатию на нее. Во-вторых, для выполнения этих задач достаточно иметь какие-то базовые знания по верстке. А в примерах указывайте соответствующую стилям разметку, если хотите показать что не так. А вообще, как по мне вопрос из разряда "Я не хочу сам думать, сделайте за меня."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(235, 30, 99, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 139, 101, 1) 100%);
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.priceinfo {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  width: 292px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #090a0b;
  color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #090a0b, -10px 0 0 #090a0b;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="button">Оставить заявку</a>
</div>

<br>

<div class="priceinfo">
  Оплата только за фактически<br> выполненные работы
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.buttom {
  /* Style for "Rounded Re" */
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #362753;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ea2363 0%, #ff8a65 100%);
  margin: auto auto 116px 130px;

  text-align: center; /* центр по горизонтали */
  line-height: 50px; /* по вертикали - но  нельзя две строки */
}
```

или

```
.buttom {
  /* Style for "Rounded Re" */
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #362753;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ea2363 0%, #ff8a65 100%);
  margin: auto auto 116px 130px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```